# Best way to split one component into multiple ones Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have one component who has in her HTML file one div, lets call divA. Inside of this div, based on some conditions (ng-container(s)) is another divB.
Both of divs have specific css style.
I need to reuse the whole html in another container, but with different content in divB.

My first option:

- create shared component for divB and inside specific component copy divA with css style and include shares component
  Downsize: duplicate divA
  Second
- shared component for divA
- shared component for divB

Downsize: separate divA from divB

Please, help me find the best solution for this case.